# Adding Table rows using jQuery in Firefox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, firefox, safari

I am trying to add rows to my repeater using jQuery using below script.It is working perfect in IE, but not in Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

looks like issue with using of outerHTML. Can someone help me?

```
function AddRowToTable(table) {
    var newRow1 = $(table.rows[table.rows.length - 2].outerHTML);
    var myRow = $(table.rows[table.rows.length - 2]);
    $(myRow).after(newRow1);
}
```

Comment: If it only works in IE there's something wrong with it... :)

Comment: You're mixing jQuery and regular Javascript DOM calls. It would probably help you to use one or the other. outerHTML is IE specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`outerHTML` is a proprietary standard, unsupported by browsers other than IE.  It's a bad idea anyway -- you should almost always just use the DOM nodes and clone them where necessary.  Fortunately, jQuery makes this very easy for you.

```
function AddRowToTable(table) {
    var $table = $(table);
    var $oldRow = $table.find('tr').eq(-2); // get the second last row
    var $newRow = $oldRow.clone(true); // clone the node
    $oldRow.after($newRow); // insert the new row after the old row
}
```

See:

- [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq)
- [`clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone)
- [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after)

Comment: This is absolutely perfect. Thank you very much.
Is there any way to read this table data from code behind in c#? I want to maintain this state in postbacks and need to send this to DB after final save.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [Add table row in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery)

The solution was

```
$('#myTable tr:last').after('<tr>...</tr><tr>...</tr>');
```

You can probably modify that to being useful in your case...

Comment: Well, the question here is about copying the existing row, so it isn't exactly a duplicate.

Comment: true, didn't actually realise that was what he was trying to do with his code... Nevertheless, cloning is not the difficulty.